# Handling submit click on the Search Widget

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

My Activity has a Search Widget implemented.

I believe it is somehow set by default that when you enter some query (so that the query window is not empty) and click "submit" or "search" button somewhere on your device it automatically reloads the same Activity (calls the onCreate() method, so on so forth).

Is there any way to catch this event so that the activity doesn't reload?

Any ideas???

**Edit:** actually what happens is it starts the same activity on the top of the old one. Start thinking it might be my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `android:launchMode= "singleTop"` to the activity description in the manifest file solved my issue.